# Linux rm can't remove files

Tags: linux, unix

I'm not able to remove any of the following files:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 15일  17:15

-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 15일  17:01 000

-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu        738  3월 15일  17:41 000000
y.c

-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 15일  16:49 1234
?Q4▒;
-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu        728  3월 15일  16:41 77777.c
▒;
-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu        728  3월 15일  16:38 77777
Q4▒;
s▒▒?s▒▒▒--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 15일  16:37 7777
-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 14일  18:02 abcd.c
4▒;-------   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 14일  18:04
-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 14일  18:08 abcde
Q4▒;
-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 14일  18:06 abcd
?Q4▒;
-rwxr-xr-x   1 os_stu_61 osstu       6696  3월 15일  19:30 copy
----------   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 14일  18:01 copy.c
G▒?s▒▒?s▒▒▒
----------   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 15일  19:28 copy.c
▒
-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 14일  17:38 copyhw2
▒;
-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 14일  17:45 hw2
▒?Q4▒;
-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu        738  3월 15일  17:42 jebal.c
sdf

-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 15일  16:52 jebal
Q4▒;
-rw-r--r--   1 os_stu_61 osstu          0  3월 15일  19:28 lala.c
```

None of the above files can be removed.

i tried `#rm hw2`
then,  `hw2: No such file or directory`

also i tried

```
# rm -rf hw2

# rm -f hw2
```

I executed my program after copying the source file to a new file.
In my program, I used system call `creat()` to create the file.
By mistake, I failed to open the source file but created a new file.

What can i do remove the files?

Comment: Did you try: `rm hw2*`? Try before `ls hw2*` to see what you will delete, just in case.

Comment: @BlueIce: it is not an error in format. Probably they passed uninitialized values to the `creat()` function, so the file names are actually this way.

Comment: @rodrigo Is the read-write-execute column supposed to be affected also?

Comment: rm hw2* works! thank you

Comment: @BlueIce: No, they probably added a '\n' in the name in place of the NUL char so the files are actually named `hw2\n▒?Q4▒;` and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your shell is bash, you can use `printf '%q\n' *` to list filenames in shell-quoted form. This will provide the names formatted in such a way that you can pass them to `rm` exactly as given.

Comment: @user3422819 Then you can `rm $'copy.c\n\254'`

Comment: @user3422819, the `$''` syntax is essential. You can't leave it out.

Comment: @user3422819 You obviously omitted the `$'` at the start and the `'` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

An unconventional way:

- `cd` to your directory
- start the emacs editor via the `emacs` command
- type `ctrl-x d <enter>` to start dired mode
- use up and down arrow keys to reach the intended file
- flag it for deletion via typing `d`
- execute via typing `x`
- answer `yes <enter>` and let emacs delete it for you
- leave emacs via typing `ctrl-x ctrl-c`

This helped me for many files with exotic names.

Answer (score 0):

You as well can try to type `rm hw2` and then press the TAB key.

This will activate the shell's command line expansion, so you'll see the full filename.

Because, what you see is a file name `hw2` followed by a newline and some other characters.